# Sending a signal to collection view within tableview cell from a segment outlet in another tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, tableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segment outlet in a tableview cell in a VC. There are two indexes: 1 and 2.

When I click on 2, I want to tell the collection view within another tableviewcell to reload another view.

And when I click back to 1, I want the same collection view to reload again and display the original content.

Here are my View Controller Functions:

```
class MyProfileTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,   UITableViewDataSource,segment
 {

 //Variable selection to determine what is selected - 1 by default
 var viewSelected = "1"

 //Segment Function - viewSelected is used to tell VC what index it's on
  func segmentSelected(tag: Int, type: String) {
    if type == "1" {
        print("1")
        viewSelected = "1"
    } else if type == "2" {
        print("2")
        viewSelected = "2"
    }
 }


 //Cell For Row - tells tableviewcell to look at viewSelected
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell  = AboutTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProfileSegmentTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ProfileSegmentTableViewCell
  cell.segmentCell = self
  return cell
  } else {
  let cell  = AboutTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "1_2Cell", for: indexPath) as! 1_2Cell
  cell.viewSelected = viewSelected
  return cell
  }
```

Here is the Segment Control TableviewCell

```
 //protocol used to delegate
 protocol segment: UIViewController {
func segmentSelected(tag: Int, type: String)
}

class ProfileSegmentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var profileSegmentControl: UISegmentedControl!

var segmentCell: segment?


  @IBAction func segmentPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    profileSegmentControl.changeUnderlinePosition()
    
    let Index = self.profileSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex
    if Index == 0
    {
        segmentCell?.segmentSelected(tag: (sender as AnyObject).tag, type: "1")
        )
    } else {
        segmentCell?.segmentSelected(tag: (sender as AnyObject).tag, type: "2")
        
    }
}
```

CollectionView

```
 //variable by default
 var viewSelected = "1"

 //viewDidLoad
 override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    cView.delegate = self
    cView.dataSource = self
    get {
        self.cView.reloadData()
        self.cView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

 func get(_ completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)  {
  getCount.removeAll() 
  if viewSelected = "1" {
  print("1") } else {
  print("2)
  }
  completionHandler()
 }
```

Comment: You might want to check out closures. Define a closure inside the collection view cell and in the table view cell. Assign the collection view cell's closure to your table view cell's closure, then call the table view cell's closure in your `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt`.

Comment: Have you got a problem with your code ?

Comment: Several issues... First, don't post "sort of" code - your `cellForRowAt` code has no `if` statement. Second, do you have only two rows, one with the segmented control and one with the collection view? If so, why in the world are you using a table view for that? Third, if you have many rows, you need to account for the cell being scrolled out of view. Fourth, you should use a closure in your segmented-control-cell to tell your **controller** to reload the row containing the collection view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very simple example of using a `closure` so your segmented-control cell can communicate with your table view controller.

Your cell class might look like this:

```
class ProfileSegmentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var profileSegmentControl: UISegmentedControl!
    
    var callback: ((Int)->())?
    
    @IBAction func segmentPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let segControl = sender as? UISegmentedControl else { return }
        // tell the controller that the selected segment changed
        callback?(segControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    }
}
```

When the user changes the selected segment, the cell uses the `callback` closure to inform the controller that a segment was selected.

Then, in your controller, you could have a `var` to track the currently selected segment index:

```
// track selected segment index
var currentIndex: Int = 0
```

and your `cellForRowAt` code would look like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        // first row - use cell with segemented control
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProfileSegmentTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ProfileSegmentTableViewCell
        
        // set the segemented control's selected index
        cell.profileSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = self.currentIndex
        
        // set the callback closure
        cell.callback = { [weak self] idx in
            guard let self = self else {
                return
            }
            // update the segment index tracker
            self.currentIndex = idx
            // reload row containing collection view
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        }
        
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        // second row - use cell with collection view
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "1_2Cell", for: indexPath) as! My_1_2Cell
        
        // tell the cell which segment index is selected
        cell.setData(currentIndex)
        
        return cell
    }
    
    // all other rows - use simple Basic cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlainCell", for: indexPath) as! PlainCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Row \(indexPath.row)"
    return cell
}
```

Here is a complete example you can run and examine: https://github.com/DonMag/ClosureExample

Comment: This worked and I added to call the function every time for cell.row to constantly check for new changes.

Answer (score -1):

You can use NotificationCenter.default.addObserver... method and  NotificationCenter.default.post..... Read about them. And don't forget to remove observers in deinit

Comment: There should be no need to remove observers in `deinit`, it's automatic. Also `NotificationCenter` is kind of a hassle to work with...

Comment: Not for all cases it's automatic. What do you suggest? The chain of closures?)... @aheze

Comment: Yeah closure chain usually works pretty well for me...